# Cannot create Phar from ZFTool of Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phar

The Phar Archive of the ZFTool can be [downloaded](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html#without-installation-using-the-phar-file) from GitHub or [created manually](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html#compile-the-phar-file).

When I try to complite the Phar on my own, I get this error:

```
user@machine:/lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool# bin/create-phar
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/vendor): failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in /lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/bin/create-phar:65
Stack trace:
#0 /lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/bin/create-phar(65): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/lib/ZendFramew...')
#1 /lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/bin/create-phar(26): addDir(Object(Phar), '/lib/ZendFramew...', '/lib/ZendFramew...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/bin/create-phar on line 65
```

It cannot find the folder `/lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/vendor`...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the procedure I use to create the PHAR archive:

```sh
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool.git
cd ZFTool
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
./bin/create-phar
```

You probably missed the composer installation, since it does not find the `vendor` directory.